# AWS EB - how to change from PHP 5.6 to 7.X?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to update my environment from PHP 5.6 to 7.1. However, I can't see any version except 5.6:
[image]

Is it possible to update PHP version? If no - is there any tutorial how can I create new environment that way it uses current database (or new database copied from existing one)?

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the Elastic Beanstalk "[Updating Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Platform Version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.platform.upgrade.html)" documentation for PHP, we see that the recommended approach is to do a Blue/Green deployment.

Coming to the second part of the query with respect to the databases :

How have you configured it ? ( is it created from the Beanstalk console ? or is the database totally independent of the Beanstalk environment ( recommended way ) [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html)

case 1 :

If the database is configured from Beanstalk console like [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html#environments-cfg-rds-create), then procedure to migrate it to a new Beanstalk environment ( with updated platform version ) is [described here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decouple-rds-from-beanstalk/)

case 2 :

If the Database is external, then we do not have any hazel, you just need to reconfigure the security group rules etc.. for the new environment and then proceed to delete the old environment. [Configuring external RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this when creating an environment. Once the environment has been created you my switch platforms from the available minor options within the major version you selected at creation (as you see in your example).

The easiest way to accomplish what you're after is to `clone` your existing environment and select the `7.x` platform version you would like during that setup process.

Comment: Unfortunately clone/copy configuration also copy PHP version and I still can't change it on new environment so it doesn't solve the problem. I've finally did it by creating new environment and manually configurating everything as it was on previous env.